# bash: Unable to run build commands via bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to run 'make' command from my bash script to build the code.

I can see that all parameters got assigned and able to display the command that i am trying to run. I could not see any issue with the command. But the issue is when it tries to run the command via bash script it fails.

`My command is :-` `./build_script LIC=1 DOCUMNETS=1 PROJECTS="cuda bfm"`

Script Snippet of parsing all the arguments and constructing make command:-

```
makeargs=""
for build_flag do
   if [[ "$build_flag " = "PROJECTS="* ]]; then
          apps =`echo $build_flag |sed "s/PROJECTS=//" `
          makeargs="$makeargs PROJECTS=\"$apps \""
   else
        makeargs="$makeargs $build_flag"
    fi
done
echo "make DCOV=1 $makeargs $maketest"
make DCOV=1 $makeargs $maketest
```

When i run the script, I can see the build command has constructed properly.

Output :-

```
make DCOV=1 LIC=1 DOCUMNETS=1 PROJECTS="cuda bfm" run_all
GNUmakefile:16: warning: overriding commands for target `/'
GNUmakefile:19: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/'
make: *** No rule to make target `bfm"'.  Stop.
```

I try to print `PROJECTS` variable in my 'GNUmakefile' present in `build_main` folder. I can see the output : `PROJECTS is "bfm` . It is not taking whole `"cuda bfm"` as a whole string.

Note:- When i try to run the same build command :- `make DCOV=1 LIC=1 DOCUMNETS=1 PROJECTS="cuda bfm" run_all` explicitly it works fine.

Seems like issue with Interpreting variables with makefile.

Any solution for this ? Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Can't see enough of your script. Either add more code, or paste your code into shellcheck.net or run your script with `bash -x build_script ...`

Comment: Hi Mark, As you can see the command is getting generated properly right? the for loop will parse the arguments and check for PROJECTS string and generates a build command.

Comment: I can't see enough of your code to tell what's wrong. Did you post it in spellcheck.net yet? Because, for example this is incorrect `make DCOV=1 $makeargs $maketest` as you haven't double quoted `"$makeargs"` or `"$maketest"`

Comment: No, I haven't posted in speelcheck.net before. We are running it as a build command i.e. make .... So its not necessary to keep double quotes right ?

Comment: Exactly, that's why I made the initial suggestions of running under `bash -x` and using shellcheck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `makeargs` string to array before passing it as an arguments group.

```
eval makeargs_array=( $makeargs )
make UVC=1 "${makeargs_array[@]}" $maketest
```

Without converting to array, if you enable debug, it shows last line interpretation as

```
make DCOV=1 LIC=1 DOCUMNETS=1 'PROJECTS="cuda' bfm '"'
```

Which is clearly ignoring double-quote and considering space as separator.
Even double-quote is getting passed as a separate argument in this case.

Explanation:

[Word-splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html)
It says,

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command
>   substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within
>   double quotes for word splitting.

If we use `"$makeargs"` i.e. surrounded by double-quote, it is not considered by word-splitting and results in `LIC=1 DOCUMNETS=1 "PROJECTS=cuda bfm"`

But again its a complete string, while requirement is to split the string to use as arguments.

So now using `$makeargs`.

Word-splitting gets in action as per the default IFS (space, tab, newline), we get result as `LIC=1` `DOCUMNETS=1` `PROJECTS="cuda` `bfm` `"`

Double-quoted part of string didn't affect the word-splitting since, subject to splitting is complete string here.

Why array worked here?

Array itself expands each element as separate word when using `@` and here no further word-splitting requires after expansion.

[Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays)

Comment: May i know why bash is interpreting this way ?